# Backbone three.js view binding

Tags: binding, view, backbone.js, three.js

Sorry for asking what is probably a very simple noob question.

I have a view, which creates geometries within a Three.js renderer - the view renders successfully the first time around. However, subsequent calls to the render function fail with an unknown reference error.

I am trying to store a reference to the rendered geometry within the view rather than the model as the model is shared between multiple browsers (and indeed the server) - using Backboneio.js

The view looks like this:

```
StarSystem.hudContact = BackboneIO.View.extend({
  el: '',
  model: '',
  initialize: function(options) {
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xFFFFFF,
    });

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, ((camera[0].position.z - this.model.get('zPos')) / 10000)));

    var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    line.position.x = ((camera[0].position.x - this.model.get('xPos')) / 10000);
    line.position.y = ((camera[0].position.y - this.model.get('yPos')) / 10000);
    line.position.z = 0;
    line.Name = this.model.get('Name');

    this._hudLine = hudScene.add(line);
    this.model.bind('update', this.render, this);
  },
  render: function(){
  console.log(this._sceneLine.position.x);
    this._hudLine.position.x = ((camera[0].position.x - this.model.get('xPos')) / 10000);
    this._hudLine.position.y = ((camera[0].position.y - this.model.get('yPos')) / 10000);
    this._hudLine.position.z = 0;

  }
});
```

So, as can be seen, I am trying to store a reference to the line (line) in this._hudLine - which is known on the first render (during the initialize call), but not thereafter (in the render call).

Any direction on how to handle this without having to rely on a global array or storing information within the model would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks!

Comment: That's strange. Once you define `this._hudline` in your `initialize()` it should be a property of the instance and continue to exist even after the first `render()` call, for the lifetime of that `hudContact` object. Is it possible that some other code somewhere else is tampering with that data and perhaps, destroying it?

Comment: Hey thanks for this - it at least confirms that I was barking up the correct tree to begin with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved with reference to the following article:

[Private and public variables to a backbone view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575630/private-and-public-variables-to-a-backbone-view)

However, I think the fundamental issue was with the original template which wrapped the view in a self executing function:

```
(function () {
  //view stuff
}).call(this);
```

rather than:

```
(function () {
  //view stuff
})();
```

A noob problem - many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

i don't actualy know what BackboneIO is, but in backbone you have to bind the render function with `_.bindAll(this,"render")` to make something like `this.model.bind('update',this.render)` work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - it was actually calling the render loop fine I think that in: this.model.bind('update', this.render, this), the second occurrence of 'this' mitigates the _.bindAll requirement - however, I have tried it both ways to no avail as yet. Will keep playing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed with reference to:

[Private and public variables to a backbone view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575630/private-and-public-variables-to-a-backbone-view)

Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: Since this link is included in your other answer, please help clean up the site by deleting this one.